# how to output date with every logback log

Tags: java, slf4j, logback

So how do I make logback output the current date every time it logs to the console/log file?
Also, I'd like to add "some string" of my choice after the log level before the date
basically I want it to look like the following:

< INFO some string> [2014-04-30 12:18:27,615] LOG MESSAGE BLA BLA

thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the pattern layout you would use something like this:

```
<pattern>&lt; %level some string &gt; [%d] %msg%n</pattern>
```

#### EDIT

After looking at the [Documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html)
You're going to have to import

```
import org.slf4j.MDC;
```

into your classes.

Then you'll do the following in your class:

```
MDC.put("custom_message", "This is my message");
```

And in your pattern do:

```
<pattern>&lt; %level %X{custom_message} &gt; [%d] %msg%n</pattern>
```

Comment: do you know how I can retrieve a string from my java code and input it as the "some string"? Basically, ever time I run the application I need to retrieve a new string value and put it in the place of the "some string"